# How to write url rewrite in codeigniter

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, url

I write the `url` rewrite in `.htaccess` in codeigniter as follows

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^Vorarlberg.html$ index.php/users/suchergeb?short_query=true&sbundesland=V&offset=0&limit=25&country=A [L]
RewriteRule ^Tirol.html$ index.php/users/suchergeb?short_query=true&sbundesland=T&offset=0&limit=25&country=A [L]
```

myproject is located in wamp server under irat.2013 folder

the above code is working but **we dont want to show full url**, we would like to show
as follows

> irat.2013/Vorarlberg.html

and one more thing if we give the full localhost `url` before the `index.php/users...` then only it is working other wise it is not.
Please help me ....

Answer (score 0):

Use the application/config/routes.php file. Check docs here: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html

Comment: Thank you for your replay I saw the above url but My problem is when we click on the link href="Vorarlberg.html" we are adding extra parameters to this link through .htaccess as above said and sending that link to users controller and  suchergeb method this is working fine but we don't want to show the url to the visitor users